# RecyclerView Android in loop

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

How to get data from `ArrayList` to `RecyclerView`?

```
ModelCoba modelCoba = response.body();

for (int i = 0; i < modelCoba.getAcara_daftar().size(); i++){
    judul[i] = response.body().getAcara_daftar().get(i).getJudul();
    pemateri[i] = response.body().getAcara_daftar().get(i).getPemateri();
    tanggal[i] = response.body().getAcara_daftar().get(i).getTgl();
}

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AcaraAdapter.this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try custom adapter [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-recyclerview-example)

Try above given example and in your  case adapter could  be used as below

> MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, modelcoba);
>
> mRecyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);